# Does "to pursue this research as a joint collaboration" sound natural?

Tags: phrase-usage

I have just finished to describe a research project and I would like to mention that I have received money to conduct this research. Does the following sentence sound natural to native speakers?

> I have received a three-year grant to pursue this research as a joint
>   collaboration between the University of City-1 and the University of
>   City-2.

Comment: Sounds natural to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Joint collaboration” is as pleonastic and redundant an expression as “another alternative”—or “pleonastic and redundant.” I would suggest you write “pursue jointly” or “pursue collaboratively” or “pursue in collaboration with”—that is, choose *between* “joint” and “collaboration,” and then use whichever you prefer for adverbial modification of your verb “pursue.” This is a question of style—getting verbs and verb phrases to carry more of the semantic load instead of loading it all onto nouns and noun phrases.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little stilted, but academic writing itself sounds that way. I think it would please your audience and they would have no problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

"Joint Collaboration" is a term utilized in Academics and Law. It is valid and widely utilized.

**Joint Collaboration** means a specific joint effort agreed to by the Parties that is based on and governed by a specific Joint Research Plan focused on a Target agreed to by the Joint Research Committee in writing.

> Example: Developing African-European joint collaboration for Science
>   and Technology
>   https://cordis.europa.eu/project/rcn/96825/factsheet/en